# RegEx trying to match anything but a certain pattern with chars from the pattern being allowed

Tags: javascript, regex, match

In this case I am trying to create a pattern that matches anything BUT a `|` or `}}` but I would like to understand how to do this in the general case as well.

That is I would like to match any character any number of times and stop once I hit either a `|` or a `}}`
So

```
[\w\s`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-\+=\[\]\\;"',<\.>\/\?\{\}:]*
```

and return when I hit `}}` or `|`

What I currently have is:

```
var regex = /[\w\s`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-\+\=\[\]\\;"',<\.>\/\?\{\}\:]*(?!((\|)|(\}\})))/
```

then something like

```
var str = "abc}}";
str.match(regex)
```

should return `abc` but mine doesn't even work even after hours using debuggex

The problem I have is I need to also be allowed to have a single `}` within my match so just taking out the `\}` from the first group doesn't work. 
I don't even understand how this is possible and in other expressions I will need to be able to recognize `[anything but {{, {:, {{{, |, }}]` and I can't grasp the logic to code this. 
Also in case I missed a special character that needs to be escaped or have a redundant backslash please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
/(.+?)(\||}}||$)/
```

That is:

- `(.+?)` non-greedy capturing match of one or more of any character
- `(\||}}||$)` capturing match of `\|` or `}}` or `$` (end of string).

The result you want will be the first captured match, i.e., the second item of the array returned by `.match()` (if there is a match):

```js
var regex = /(.+?)(\||\}\}|$)/;
console.log("abc}}".match(regex));
console.log("abc}def}}".match(regex));
console.log("abc}123}456}}x".match(regex));
console.log("abc|def".match(regex));
console.log("abc".match(regex));
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works. I think the issue is that it still sees }} as part of (.+)

Comment: Also is there a reason for the $? It should be able to work even when it isn't the end of a string so something like **bold**"abc}}123"**bold** would still match only **bold**"abc"**bold** but it should also be able to handle something like **bold**"abc}123}456}}x"**bold** and match **bold**"abc}123}456"**bold**

Comment: Did you click "run code snippet" and see that it *does* work? As I mentioned in the second dot-point above, the `$` is part of a sub match that matches `|` *or* `}}` *or* the end of the string. I've edited my answer to include your example `"abc}123}456}}x"` as one of my test cases.

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand at first. So in the array returned the desired result would be in the [1] index? Is there a reason for this? Also would the same logic be applied for the case where it would have to be anything but **{{, {:, {{{, |, }}** ?

Comment: Yes, array index 1, because that's how sub-matches work, where array index 0 is the whole match. (You could change the second set of parentheses to be a non-capturing match if you don't want that also included at array index 2.) For your other cases, if you just want to expand the possibilities to include `{{`, etc., then yes, just add more options within the second `()` group.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`var regex = /(.*[^}}|\|])/`

The `()` indicate a capturing group, which is how you get it to return `abc` in your example.

Generally translated:

`.*` any number of any characters...

`[^` except for...

`}}|\|]` }} or |.

(Tip - https://regex101.com/ is a pretty handy tool for generating and testing regular expressions.)

Comment: `[^` is used to match anything other than the *individual* characters that follow, so you can't use it for `[^}}`...

Comment: Incredible! that is so much simpler. So for the case where I would need anything but {{, {:, {{{, |, }} I would just apply the same logic and through those 5 into the end of the expression?

Comment: Or not.. let me double check

Comment: Yeah nnnnnn is correct it fails when I have something like abc|123